# How can I know if $2^{2^{2^{2^{2}}}}+1=?$ is prime?

Tags: calculus, number-theory, prime-numbers

I could calculate the following prime numbers 
$$2+1=3$$
$$2^{2}+1=5$$
$$2^{2^{2}}+1=17$$
$$2^{2^{2^{2}}}+1=65537$$

Are the following numbers prime??? $$2^{2^{2^{2^{2}}}}+1=?$$ $$2^{2^{2^{2^{2^{2}}}}}+1=??$$

Comment: $65537$ is "the largest known prime of the form $2^{2^n}+1$"; acording to Wikipedia.

Comment: All the  Fermat numbers up to about $1 + 2^{2^n}$ for $5 \leq n \leq 32$ are proved composite, although sometimes no factor is known. See if you can put your numbers in the Fermat format... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number

Comment: @Pedro We don't know that for sure, it's just conjectured.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I forgot the word "known", of course.

Comment: @Bye_World Mersenne primes are of the form $2^p-1$. Here we have Fermat primes.

Comment: I do not know, if it is a strict mathematical rule, but it is consense that $\large a^{b^c}=a^{(b^c)}$

Comment: $2^{32}+1=641 \times 6700417$ was found by (if I remember right) Euler to disprove Fermat's conjecture that all numbers of the form $\large 2^{2^n}+1$ are primes.

Comment: It is very likely that there are no fermat primes above $65537$.

Comment: The WolframAlpha could calculate the number, but  doesn't know if the number prime or not.

Comment: [Here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/a9MOG.png) is the number $2^{2^{\large16}}$, in all its splendor $($almost $20,000$ digits$)$. Its successor is not divisible by any of the first $10^7$ primes.

Comment: @lucian You mean $2^{2^{16}}+1$

Comment: @Peter: Yes, exactly. $($See edit$)$.

Comment: The factorizations of the fermat numbers seem to be stored upto $2^{256}+1$ in wolfram alpha. isprime(...) reveals them.

Comment: $825753601$ and $188981757975021318420037633$ are factors of $F_{16}$

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$
2^{2^{2^{2^2}}}+1=2^{2^{16}}+1=F_{16},
$$
the $16$-th Fermat number, and
$$
2^{2^{2^{2^{2^2}}}}+1=2^{2^{65536}}+1=F_{65536}.
$$
All Fermat numbers $F_n$ for $5\le n \le 32$ are known to be composite ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number)).  Summaries of factoring status are given [here](http://www.prothsearch.net/fermat.html).  Specifically, $F_{16}$ is known to be divisible by
$$
1575\cdot 2^{19} + 1 = 825753601
$$
and
$$
180227048850079840107 \cdot 2^{20} + 1 = 188981757975021318420037633.
$$
As far as I can tell, nothing is known about the primality of $F_{65536}$.